# Checking for Null goes into infinite loop

Tags: java, object, null, nullpointerexception, structure

I've got the data structure as follows:

[object] -> [object] -> [objects]

each object has a right pointer to another one.

```
while (currentParcel.getRight() != null) {
    currentParcel = currentParcel.getRight();
}
```

This code goes into an infinite loop.

By my logic it should go right as much as it can, and only when it reached null, currentParcel object should be the last object with pointer to the null (has no object to the right).

How can I tackle the infinite looping?

I've tried writing it in following way:

```
boolean found = false;
try {
   while (found == false) {
       currentParcel = currentParcel.getRight();

       if (currentParcel.getRight() == null)
       {
           currentParcel.addRight(p);
           System.out.println(currentParcel);
           found = true;
       } 

   }
} 
catch (NullPointerException e) {}
```

But it did not work for me. It simply does not go as far to the right as it can.

Comment: Have you checked the linked list itself? You've probably got a circular linked list. Also, you should never catch a NPE.

Comment: It is not circular for sure. I am not using a linkedlist here. Simply implemented described above data structure in objects.

Comment: You may not be using the the core Java LinkedList class, but you've created a linked list data structure of your own, and before you say that "it's not circular for sure", you'd better check it. Until you have your solution in hand, don't disregard any possible cause of your problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have tree-structure actually. Didnt write here that there's a pointer to another object. So, basically there are two pointers from one objects (one to top and other to right). 
The last object does not points to the first. I do not have anything like that in my code.

Comment: Make sure your objects have a decent `toString()` method and print them out inside of the loop, and then you'll see your circular list. And I didn't say that "the last points to the first", just that there's a circular connection somewhere. You'd best find it.

Comment: Catching exceptions is fine; just don't swallow them! And of the exceptions, NPE is the one that should terminate your program: otherwise you're using the catch as flow control.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a circular link in your linked list structure. To debug this, either use a debugger or println the objects in your while loop to see what they are. This way you will find the problem. Make sure your objects have a decent `toString()` method and print them out inside of the loop for one way to identify your circular connection. Also, you don't have to have "the last points to the first" for this to occur, but rather all you need is just for a circular connection to exist somewhere. You'd best find it.

Comment: The problem that I have only one object in my structure. When I try to add another, it should find the right most object and add pointer to new object. First object is added, however another is not. And it is stuck in this loop. toString method showed only one object in the list also.

Comment: @Lythium: consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org), a small program that we can compile and run, that uses the nucleus of your code and that reproduces your problem. Chances are if you attempt this, you'll see the problem as you isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is OK, the problem is somewhere else, this works fine

```
    Parcel p1 = new Parcel();
    Parcel p2 = new Parcel();
    Parcel p3 = new Parcel();
    p1.setRight(p2);
    p2.setRight(p3);
    Parcel currentParcel = p1;
    while (currentParcel.getRight() != null) {
        currentParcel = currentParcel.getRight();
    }
```